# Windows 10 OpenSSH Server Key Exchange Algorithm is not Supported?

Tags: ssh, windows-10, tfsbuild, openssh

I have a TFS build that uses the [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=vsts) build step which connects my VM to an external Windows 10 machine that I have been running for the last ~12 months. Recently, the remote Win10 machine received [Windows 10 feature update 1709](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/), which required me to perform a bunch of setup to get the SSH server working again.

Because the installed version of OpenSSH apparently only supports "ED25519" key exchange alogrithms, I have needed to update all of my SSH clients (ie Putty) to connect to the ssh server, otherwise I would receive this error:

```
Couldn't agree on a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256.curve25519-sha256@libssh.org)
```

Updating to Putty 0.70 fixed that. However, from what I can tell I have no way to update the TFS build task listed above to support the new (and only?) key echange alogrithm. I only get this message in my build:

```
==========================================================================
Task         : Copy Files Over SSH
Description  : Copy files or build artifacts to a ******** machine over SSH
Version      : 0.115.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821894)
==========================================================================
Setting up SSH connection to ******** host TestAgent1.
Failed to connect to ******** machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details. Failed to connect to ******** machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details. 
Error: Handshake failed: no matching key exchange algorithm..
```

Is there a way to update this TFS build step to use a key exchange algorithm supported by OpenSSH? If not, can I change my Windows 10 OpenSSH server settings to allow more key exchange algorithms?

Comment: Try to create a new SSH endpoint to see what result you will get.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I deleted my endpoint and recreated it, I still get the key exchange error.

Comment: Have you tried re-generate private key?